# Return View not refreshing browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem with return this.View("Index",model) (after the database processing) refreshing the browser when I upload an 80Mb file. The code works fine on smaller files. The code also works when I upload an 80Mb file with the debugger attached to w3wp.exe and manually step through it. I have tried multiple browsers and have the same problem across all of them.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ImportDataViewModel model)
    {
        string importFileLoc = string.Empty;

        if (Request.Files.Count != 0)
        {
            importFileLoc = this.SaveTempFile(Request.Files[0]);
        }

        if (!this.ValidateImportModel(model))
        {
            model.SystemNames = this.GetSystemNames().SetSelected(model.SelectedSystem);
            return this.View(model);
        }

        // Do Database and other data processing here

        if (!ModelState.IsValid || model.ContainsWarnings)
        {
            model.SystemNames = this.GetSystemNames(model.SelectedSystem);
            return this.View("Index", model);
        }

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: Also, i would try to debug HTTP request with Google Chrome tools (F12/Network) it might say timed out or something.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have already modified the web.config for file sizes and timeout to eight hours. The file is getting uploaded to the server fine. I will checkout Chrome tools to see if something else is going wrong.

Comment: Also check if browsers have their own time-outs.

Comment: if it works on smaller files you might try adding a delay to the load for larger files